# Let T be the following family of subsets of $\mathbb R$: A ∈ T ⇔ (x ∈ A ⇒ −x ∈ A). Prove that A ⊂ R is open if and only if A is closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Can someone prove that for me please or at least tell what kind a way i should follow through. I did not understand the question itself actually like "A is the subset of T and it is closed if and only if A is open". That is what i understand but it does not make any sense to me. I am very new at topology and probably i missing something so if someone can eplain it to me that would be great.

Comment: For any $a>0$ the interval $A = (-a,a)$ seems to satisfy the condition, but $A$ is not closed in the standard topology of $\mathbb R$

Comment: To begin with, you should check if $T$ is a topology on ${\mathbb R}$, otherwise its elements cannot qualify as "open." Second, you will be working with subsets $A\subset {\mathbb R}$, not with subsets of $T$. As for the question itself, it's asking you to prove that whenever $A\in T$, its complement ${\mathbb R}\setminus A$ is also in $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is open, then $x\in A^c \implies x\notin A \implies -x\notin A \implies -x\in A^c$ so $A^c$ is open and $A$ is closed. If $A$ is closed, then $A^c$ is open and so closed and so $A$ is open.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Can you explain me what is A^c means.

Comment: The middle implication could use some expanding. The contrapositive of $x \in A \implies -x \in A$ is $-x \notin A \implies x \notin A$. Replacing $x$ with $\color{red}{-x}$, and recalling that $-(-x) = x$, we get$$x \notin A \implies -(\color{red}{-x}) \notin A \implies \color{red}{-x} \notin A.$$

Comment: @OnurAktan $A^c$ is one of the many notations for the complement. In this case, $A^c$ refers to $\Bbb{R} \setminus A$ or $\Bbb{R} - A$, or however you normally notate the complement of $A$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh okay I get it  sorry in my language we put T instead of C on the top of the set symbol thats why I got confused. thank you for the answer.